What should I do if I run a mpc_local_planner in the GitHub website in ros and there is a problem with the program?
enter image description here
The trolley model stops, road strength planning cannot be carried out, and the added log information cannot be output, ask for a solution!
I would like to know how to fix this and how I can add rosinfo to be able to output information.
